# How to split the elements of a specific column in a dataframe created from a csv file in PySpark?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I have created a dataframe in PySpark from a csv file with data with columns in the following format:

```
       +---+--------------+-------------+
       | ID|        FileID|       TestID|
       +---+--------------+-------------+
       |  1| HD_Fly_456_34|Gone_YT_78_67|
       |  2|FG_Home_567_54|Gone_YT_78_22|
       |  3|  GD_Go_678_87|Gone_YT_06_82|
       |  4| GH_Buy_908_45|Gone_YT_92_70|
       |  5| HJ_Get_789_65|Gone_YT_98_43|
       +---+--------------+-------------+
```

I used the following lines of code to create a dataframe:

```
   df=sqlc.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("testfile.csv")
```

I need to split the elements of the columns FileID, TestID and so on at the _ (underscore) so that they can be stored in a new column.
I am using the following method:

```
     df.join(df['FileID'].str.split('_', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'R', 1:'R1',2:'R2',3:'R3'}))
```

I get the following error:

```
 df.join(df['FileID'].str.split('_', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'R', 1:'R1',2:'R2',3:'R3'}))

   TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

How do I get to where I need to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While sometimes similar, PySpark is not the same as Pandas.

I'd use `split`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, col

parts = split("TestID", "_")

df.select(
    parts[0].alias("R"), parts[1].alias("R1"), 
    parts[2].alias("R2"),  parts[3].alias("R3"))
```